# metal compute shader: setting alpha to zero does not yield complete transparency

Tags: ios, swift, shader, gpu, metal

I am trying to modify this guy's code:

https://github.com/FlexMonkey/MetalVideoCapture

which takes in video from the iphone / ipad camera and filters it with some Metal GPU compute kernels in real time.

I would like to alter the Metal code to do some simple chroma keying, where we make a certain color in the video transparent (i.e. for that color alpha = 0).

The problem is that the resulting video output from the metal compute kernel never reaches full transparency, even if you force alpha to zero at the end of the metal compute kernel:

```
outTexture.write(float4(float3(rgb), 0.0), gid);
```

The resultant video is only partially transparent.

Note that I am setting
layer.opaque = false 
for the MTKView where the rendering is being done.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

This is the result with alpha = 0 and a red background for the UIView:

[image]

So Columbo's answer worked for me and here is the code for my chromakey filter:

```
kernel void ChromaKey(texture2d<float, access::read> yTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                   texture2d<float, access::read> cbcrTexture [[texture(1)]],
                                   texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(2)]],
                                   uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    float2 green = float2(54.0/255.0, 34.0/255.0);
    float threshold = 0.05;
    float3 colorOffset = float3(-(16.0/255.0), -0.5, -0.5);
    float3x3 colorMatrix = float3x3(
                                    float3(1.164,  1.164, 1.164),
                                    float3(0.000, -0.392, 2.017),
                                    float3(1.596, -0.813, 0.000)
                                    );

    uint2 cbcrCoordinates = uint2(gid.x / 2, gid.y / 2);
    float y = yTexture.read(gid).r;
    float2 cbcr = cbcrTexture.read(cbcrCoordinates).rg;
    float alpha = smoothstep(threshold, threshold + 0.5, distance(cbcr, green));
    float3 ycbcr = float3(y, cbcr);
    float4 rgba = alpha * float4(colorMatrix * (ycbcr + colorOffset), 1.0);
    outTexture.write(rgba, gid);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that your layer is using premultiplied alpha ([mentioned here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/AlphaCompositingOperations/AlphaCompositingOperations.html)). If that's the case, then you have two easy solutions:

1. Change the layer from premultiplied alpha compositing to use non-premultiplied alpha compositing.
2. Change the compute kernels to perform the alpha premultiplication.

To do #2 you would change something like this:

```
float alpha = <something_or_other>;
float3 rgb = colorMatrix * (ycbcr + colorOffset);
outTexture.write(float4(float3(rgb), alpha), gid);
```

To something like this:

```
float alpha = <something_or_other>;
float3 rgb = (colorMatrix * (ycbcr + colorOffset)) * alpha;
outTexture.write(float4(float3(rgb), alpha), gid);
```

Comment: If I am hardcoding my alpha for every pixel as 0, I don't understand why I should see any video at all. Shouldn't it be completely transparent? My understanding is that premultiplying the image by alpha darkens those pixels for which alpha is not 1.0. I don't see how that would affect the transparency when I am forcing alpha to zero for every pixel.

Comment: This site explains the maths and the reasoning for premultiplied blending: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha/

Comment: Ok, so my next question would be: is there any way to change the state of premultiply by alpha for a metal compute pipeline?
I have seen an example of doing it for a render pipeline here:


<http://metalbyexample.com/translucency-and-transparency/>


but not an example for doing it with a compute pipeline.

Comment: I think the suggested technique still applies. The crux of the matter is that your color data must be in a premultiplied alpha format to be composited correctly by Core Animation, so at the end of the pipeline (whether that's a compute shader writing to a drawable, or you're returning a color from a fragment function), you should multiply RGB through by alpha.

Comment: Great answer. I had to change my Fragment Shader as follows to make the transparency work.
From:
gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, alpha);
to:
gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * alpha, alpha);